# BOOL method doesn't works in if statement

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have an `NSArray`, which stores my contacts (strings). I also have a method called `checkList` which looking for existing contacts, if a user is not on the contact list I give an alert view to the current user where she can add the other user to her contact list. The problem is, that the `[self addContact]` is being called every single time when I tap the button, it doesn't matter, that the other user is on the contact list or not. However the `[self addContact]` should be called only when the other user isn't on the contact list.

```
- (void) checkList {

    AppDelegate *contact = (AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

     BOOL isObjectThere = [contact.cArray containsObject: self.stringToCompare];

     NSLog(@" dev log %@", contact.cArray);

    if (!isObjectThere) {
         [self addContact];
    }

}
```

I know I'm calling the `checkList` method everytime when the user taps the `goButton`, but there is an if statement which should handle the situation. I think the problem is with the BOOL, because I can properly log the `dev log`, it's not a nil, and it contains the right content.

```
- (IBAction) goButton {

[self checkList];

}
```

If somebody sees what did I wrong or have any suggestions, it would be amazing to hear about it.

When I log the BOOL it returns 0 always, so it is false everytime, it doesn't matter if the user is contact or not.

Comment: Are you sure `self.stringToCompare` is having the string which you want to add?

Comment: Maybe your self.stringToCompare returning nil , if so The Bool returns NO anyway , and your add contact method will be called eveytime you call the check list.

Comment: @user1190882 yes, it's sure. I checked it several times, and using that variable in the addContact method.

Comment: Can you show the actual log of `contact.cArray` (or at least the record you think matches) and what's contained in `self.stringToCompare`? My guess is that your array actually contains dictionary objects with details about a contact and not just strings.

Comment: Show us the actual NSLog output of stringToCompare and cArray.

Comment: @Stonz2 self.stringToCompare is a name, but you opened my mind, the array contains custom objects, and these objects contain the string values. So tdelepine's loop will be a great starting point, I will loop trough the array and check each key of the obj.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am surprised that you use containsObject. This method compares the pointer type and not the value of objects. I Sugere you use year enumerate function

```
BOOL IsObjectThere = NO; 
[contact.cArray enumerateObjectsUsingBlock: ^ (NSString * obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL * stop) {
     if ([obj isEqualToString: self.stringToCompare]) {
          isObjectThere = YES; 
         * stop = YES; // Stop enumerating 
     } 
     else {
         * stop = NO; // Continue enumerating 
     } 

}];
```

You can use also a simple loop :

```
BOOL IsObjectThere = NO; 
for (NSString* contactItem in contact.cArray)
{
     if ([obj isEqualToString: self.stringToCompare]) {
          isObjectThere = YES; 
          break;
     } 
}
```

Finally i prefere use :

```
NSUInteger index = [contact.cArray indexOfObjectWithOptions:NSEnumerationConcurrent 
                                                passingTest:^(NSString* obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) 
                    {
                        if ([obj isEqualToString: self.stringToCompare]) {
                            *stop = YES;
                            return YES;
                        }
                        return NO;
                    }];
if (index != NSNotFound) 
{
   .......
}
```

Comment: This is not true: "I am surprised that you use containsObject. This method compares the pointer and not the value". The method containsObject calls isEqual:, not the equality operator (==)

Comment: @MarcosCrispino isEqual: compares a string to an object, and will return NO if the object is not a string.

Comment: I've started to implement the second version, it's much shorter. Why do you prefer the third one?

Comment: @w88 I prefere the third because i retrieves two infos in same times the existance of Item and the index in the array.

Comment: @tdelepine "isEqual: compares a string to an object, and will return NO if the object is not a string" which is exactly what your code does.